# delete var/lib/mysql folders after dropping database via mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am aware that you don't want to remove the innodb tables from `/var/lib/mysql` for a linux distro of mysql (I have Ver 14.14).  So I used the command

```
drop database mydb1; 
drop database mydb2; 
-- etc
```

but see that the folders `mydb1` and `mydb2` etc. are sill in `/var/lib/mysql`, and the .MYD, .MYI and .frm files are there in most cases.  Are the database folders safe to manually delete now?  I know the innodb files are very sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

First, MySQL latest version is 8.x.x, so it's impossible for you to have 14.x, check that.

Second, maybe your data dir is not /var/lib/mysql. To check this variable run the following script and check the actual datadir for your instance.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%';
> +----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
> | Variable_name              | Value                                      |
> +----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
> | basedir                    | /usr/local/mysql-max-4.0.13-pc-linux-i686/ |
> | datadir                    | /usr/local/mysql/data/                     |
```

Also check for any errors when you run the DROP DATABASE sentence.